# I really dont understand why im getting the error when creating template class shared pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I dont understand the error message that im getting and i have no idea how to fix that;

```
template<typename T>
class shared_pointer
{
    private:
        static int howManyObjects;
        T* pointer;
    public:
        shared_pointer( T* p=nullptr)
        {
            pointer=p;
        }
        shared_pointer( shared_pointer& a)
        {
            a.pointer=this->pointer;
            howManyObjects++;
        }
        ~shared_pointer()
        {
            if(howManyObjects==1) delete pointer;
        }

        T& operator *()
        {
            return *pointer;
        }
        T* operator ->()
        {
            return pointer;
        }
};
template<typename T>
int shared_pointer<T>::howManyObjects=0;

int main()
{
    int b=5;
    int* wsk=&b;
    shared_pointer<int> a= shared_pointer<int>(wsk);
    return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:25: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘shared_pointer<int>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘shared_pointer<int>’
  shared_pointer<int> a= shared_pointer<int>(wsk);

In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
smartpp.cpp:14:2: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘shared_pointer<T>::shared_pointer(shared_pointer<T>&) [with T = int]’
  shared_pointer( shared_pointer& a)
```

Comment: The copy-constructor should get const reference.

Comment: Once you fix that error, you should know that your program won't work. It will attempt to delete a pointer to an object on the stack.

Comment: Why are you trying to reimplement the wheel (aka `std::shared_ptr`) yourself? Just use what the the standard library already provides, rather than reimplementing it yourself (incorrectly).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I suggest we give OP a benefit of doubt and assume they do that as a learning exercise.

Comment: @SergeyA How did I not do that? I just *asked*. A reply of "doing it as a learning exercise" is totally fine. I just wanted to know the *why*.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the copy constructor as written is backwards: it copies the (uninitialized) `pointer` in the object under construction into the object being copied (`a`). Also, in `main`, creating a shared pointer that points at an object on the stack will do bad things when the shared pointer attempts to delete the object.

Comment: I also think that the `howManyObjects` static field will probably not do what is expected - the reference count in a `shared_ptr` should be the number of instances of `shared_ptr` that exist for a given pointer, not the total number globally.

Comment: @JesperJuhl your comment: "Just use what the the standard library already provides" indicates that you foreclosed OP's explanation by giving them advice **before** they had a chance to answer *why*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl By recreating things like that i will learn more. At least thats what I think;

Comment: @SergeyA OK. I can see how it could be interpreted that way. But that was not actually what I intended. I merely wanted to ask "why?" and say that "if you don't know the "why", then just use what's already there".  I should have worded that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the copy constructor function:

```
shared_pointer( shared_pointer& a)
{
    a.pointer = this->pointer;
    howManyObjects++;
}
```

So, according to the space before the type of parameter a, you probably know that it's have to be a const by the copy constructor rules. But, when you tried to put there a `const` you got the following error:

```
shared_pointer(const shared_pointer& a)
{
    a.pointer = this->pointer; // Compilation error: assignment of member ‘shared_pointer<int>::pointer’ in read-only object
    howManyObjects++;
}
```

So you tried to remove the `const` and got the error you displayed in your post. The problem wasn't the const you tried to put there, but the assignment direction. You don't want to modify the parameter value, but the current object value. Change your copy constructor to the following and everything will be good:

```
shared_pointer(const shared_pointer& a)
{
    this->pointer = a.pointer; // Pay attention that this get the value of a, and not the opposite.
    howManyObjects++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation of what I did wrong, by far the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define move assignment operator

```
shared_pointer& operator=(shared_pointer&& other)
{
    pointer = other.pointer;
    return *this;
}
```

there are a lot of things you are missing. I list some.

`~shared_pointer()` doesn't decrease the reference count.
Because of this `int* wsk=&b;`: your `dtor` will delete a pointer in stack you SHOULD not do that.
`howManyObjects` should not be static. It should also be changed atomically if you care about thread safety.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `int* wsk = &b;`. It creates a pointer on the stack to an object on the stack. Both go out of scope at the end of the block in which they are defined, so there is no lifetime problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right it has no problem here. Just a general recommendedationi I  edit it